# transposing a 2Dvector/matrix

Tags: c++

I have the following 2d vector/matrix `X` and a vector `Y` as below:

```
std::vector<double> Y; 
unsigned int ctr=2;
std::vector<std::vector<double> >X(ctr,Y);
```

I now want to create a transpose of X,i.e. Xtrans, so am declaring it as below

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> >Xtrans(Y,ctr);
```

but it gives me the following compilation error:

```
test.cpp:128:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<double> >::vector(std::vector<double>&, unsigned int&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:241:7: note: candidates are: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::vector<double>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<double> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> = std::vector<std::vector<double> >]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:227:7: note:                 std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector::size_type, const value_type&, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<double>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<double> >, std::vector::size_type = unsigned int, value_type = std::vector<double>, allocator_type = std::allocator<std::vector<double> >]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:215:7: note:                 std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<double>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<double> >, allocator_type = std::allocator<std::vector<double> >]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:207:7: note:                 std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector() [with _Tp = std::vector<double>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<double> >]
```

How do I go about declaring Xtrans correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Besides what the others already said about fixing the code, I'd like to comment on using `vector<vector<double> >` as a matrix representation which is very inefficient and almost never what you want. A co-worker of mine once inherited a code using this style. Transforming it to simple `vector<double>` with appropriate index fiddling functions increased the performance by a factor of **thirty**. Resist the temptation.

You might want to look into one of the many available matrix libraries for C++ (e.g. [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/), [uBlas](http://www.boost.org/libs/numeric) or [mtl4](http://www.mtl4.org) to name a few; there are many others).

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two problems here - the first is that you might have misunderstood how `std::vector`'s are constructed, and the fact that when you do

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> >Xtrans(Y,ctr);
```

it's generating a compiler error because there is no constructor that matches your declaration.

One of the constructors for `std::vector` ( i.e. the one you used to declare `X` ) is declared like this:

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

so when you did `(ctr, Y)` that worked out fine - because you were telling the compiler that you wanted to create a `std::vector` of size `ctr` of whatever the value of `Y` is. (In your case `Y` is an empty `std::vector<double>` - so you got a vector of `ctr` entries, where each entry is an empty `std::vector<double>`)

So simply swapping `ctr` and `Y` in the hopes that you'll get a transposed `std::vector` is not going to work here.

And the second problem is how you actually transpose the values. You actually need to figure out an algorithm that does the tranpose of X and then pushes those values to Xtrans. Transposing the values is a different thing from actually constructing the vector. Most likely, your algorithm would be something like - construct `XTrans`, and then iterate over 'X`and insert values into`XTrans`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. To construct `XTrans`, do I start by declaring it as a 2d vector and not passing any arguments. Since I want to transpose `X`, should I just write an iterator on X and insert values into XTrans.

Comment: Yes maybe to start with construct `XTrans` as you suggest - declare it as an empty 2d vector - i.e. a `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` of size `ctr` - just like you the way you did for `X`. And then iterate through `X`. But remember it's 2 dimensional, so you've got an outer iterator which will iterate over `ctr` members - but your members are std::vector<double>, (which are currently empty - you just declared `ctr` empty `std::vector<double>`'s) so you will have an inner iterator for each of your `ctr` `std::vector<double>`'s .

Comment: I forgot to add that before iterating over `X` in order to populate `XTrans`, you will need to first populate `X` with something (or maybe not... if you use iterators the algorithm will work, it just won't do anything :-) )

Comment: can you post some sample code for the iteration algo, assuming that X is populated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make the code compile you could declare `Xtrans` as follows

```
std::vector<double> Y;
unsigned int ctr=2;
std::vector<std::vector<double> >X(ctr,Y);
std::vector<double> ctr_vector(2);
std::vector<std::vector<double> >Xtrans(Y.size(),ctr_vector);
```

however, you would have to populate Xtrans in order to use it as a transposed version of X

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misinterpreting the constructor syntax for `std::vector`. [Check here for more info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/).

Calling `std::vector<std::vector<double> >X(ctr,Y)` has the effect of creating `ctr` number of copies of `Y` and storing it into X. So fundamentally, `X` is still a 1-dimensional object, it's just that at each index of `X` you get back another `std::vector`, a copy of `Y`.

So your later syntax `std::vector<std::vector<double> >Xtrans(Y,ctr)` does not match any constructor for type `std::vector`. You don't construct a 2-D array like you would in NumPy or  Matlab.

You may want to have a look at [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/26737/) too. Probably the best thing for you is to write your own transpose function that manually places the entries into a new array in a loop.